# mysql select CURDATE() by where class in new timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

i have updated table as below:

```
<?php
   $date = new DateTime();
   $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
   $fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $sql="update mytable set logged_on='$fdate' where id='$Id'";
  ?>
```

Then i tried to select the current date as below :

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $sql="select * from mytable where DATE(logged_on) = CURDATE()";
   ?>
```

But the CURDATE() is not working. please tell me how to select the current date by where class.

Comment: Use `sysdate()` once

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
<?php
   $date = new DateTime();
   $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
   $fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $sql="select * from mytable where DATE(logged_on) = Date($fdate)" 
?>
```

But i thing the better answer is

```
<?php
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
      $con->query("SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Calcutta'");
      $con->query("SET time_zone = '+05:30'");
      $con->query("SET @@session.time_zone = '+05:30'");
      $sql="select * from mytable where DATE(logged_on) = CURDATE()";
?>
```